# Can't change Fault detail element in SOAPFault handler (in handleFault method)

Tags: web-services, websphere, axis, soapfault, soaphandler

I am using JAX-WS web services on Websphere V8. When the WS returns SOAP fault I want to do some updates in detail element. So I created SOAP handler:

```
 public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {
    try {
        SOAPMessage msg = messageContext.getMessage(); 
        SOAPBody body = msg.getSOAPBody();
        Detail d = body.getFault().getDetail();
        Node esbException = d.getFirstChild();

        // do some changes in detail element...

        // save changes
        msg.saveChanges();

        return true;
    } catch ....
    return true;
}
```

I can update the Fault message, but client gets the original Fault (before changes). But when I print the updated Fault (in soap handler) I can see the changes (e.g. call msg.writeTo(System.out)).

Any clue why the updated Fault is not returned to ws client?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to the following bug in WebSphere: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM39817